# Image Processing package/tool for warehouse system

Tags: php, laravel, npm, eloquent

Might be shooting blind here. But I have a warehouse system. I want to build in something where I can use a phone or barcode scanner to scan the label from a package and populate a form with the tracking number and customer name without writing manual. The application is build in Laravel.

Example.
A box comes in with a label with the tracking number, customer name. Want to scan or take a picture within the app to extract that information and populate a form.

Comment: Barcode scanner basically work like keyboards, they are quite easy to implement in a app. For a phone you would need to use some kind of API? My point is, phones and scanners are very different.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yeh we have barcodes implemented already that scans the barcode and get the tracking number. But the customer details don't come in the barcode. Guess the barcode wouldn't work but need like a phone or some API I can use. Im thinking they use the phone or tablet to open the form. Then open the camera and take a picture of the label then the API or package would process that image and fill out the form

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I misunderstood you. It seems you're talking about [ORC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) here, that is going to be difficult. Some labels have a [QR-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code), or something similar, that contain all the customer data, and some more advanced hand scanners can scan these. That will be the easier option to implement.

Comment: > `Want to scan or take a picture within the app to extract that information and populate a form`    => I've looked into that one long time ago. Yes, you need some OCR, ORC tooling. I thought Vue had some packages for that. The thing is: when the box comes in, does it come as a surprise? Or do you know that it's coming, maybe program something for that? Then all you have to do is scan the barcode. There are packages out there that handle barcodes